# CodeIgniter API keys in database

Tags: php, codeigniter, api

I have API keys from users in my database and need them to use in CodeIgniter.
What is the safest way to do this.
Store them in a session, use as a global var or something else?

Comment: well session is the best way to store your keys.

Comment: I agree with @saty use session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as following:

Model:

```
function get_user_key($user_id) {
  return $this->db->select('key')->from('api_keys')->where->('user_id' => $user_id)->get()->row();
}
```

Controller:

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('api_key')) {
  $key = $this->model_name->get_user_key($user_id);
  $this->session->set_userdata('api_key', $key);
} else {
  $key = $this->session->userdata('api_key');
}
```

Use $key for the user session.